# Why can I not get my items to display on my webpage when I press my save for later button

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a basic webpage using HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have added a button to certain elements on my homepage on my html that when pressed should create a new object, then pushes that object to an array and then saves that item on local storage. another function should then display the items in that array the moment you go to the saved for later page. The program is able to do all of this except display the items on the webpage, the program picks up the array saved in local storage but I haven't been able to get it to be displayed.

```
//JAVASCRIPT
function carsForLater(arr){
    let nameOfCar = prompt("Please state a name for the item being saved for later")
    let decription = prompt("Please give a description of the item being saved for later.")

    const newObj = {Name: nameOfCar, Description: decription};
    arr.push(newObj)

    localStorage.setItem("SaveForLaterArray", JSON.stringify(arr));
    alert(`There are ${arr.length} amount of items in your save for later`)
    

}
//THIS FUNCTION ALLOWS THE USER TO SEE THE ITEMS THEY HAVE SAVED ON THE WEBPAGE
function displaySavedForLater(arr){
    let blue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SaveForLaterArray"))
    let displayArea = document.querySelector("displayItems")
    

    arr.forEach((item) => {
        let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.textContent = "";
        displayArea.appendChild(newDiv);

        let displaySavedItems = document.createElement("p");
        displaySavedItems.textContent = `${item.Name}: ${item.Description}`
        newDiv.appendChild(displaySavedItems)
    })

    console.log(blue)
}



<!-- THE BUTTON ON THE HOME PAGE -->
<button type="button" id="Foxbody" onclick="carsForLater(SaveForLaterArray)">Save</button>


<!-- WHAT I HAVE DONE FOR THE SAVE FOR LATER HTML PAGE -->
<body onload="displaySavedForLater(SaveForLaterArray)">
<div class="row">

        <div class="displayItems">

        </div>
<body>
```

Comment: you read from storage `let blue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SaveForLaterArray"))` ... then never use `blue`, you use the passed in `arr` ... which is ... `SaveForLaterArray` ... a non-existent variable

Comment: Also the selector is wrong, should be `.displayItems`.

Answer (score 0):

in above code error have a function have a arrgument that why you get a error on browser console this is updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body onload="displaySavedForLater()">

    <button type="button" id="Foxbody" onclick="carsForLater()">Save</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="displayItems"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let SaveForLaterArray = [];

        function carsForLater() {
            let nameOfCar = prompt("Please state a name for the item being saved for later");
            let decription = prompt("Please give a description of the item being saved for later.");

            const newObj = { Name: nameOfCar, Description: decription };
            SaveForLaterArray.push(newObj);

            localStorage.setItem("SaveForLaterArray", JSON.stringify(SaveForLaterArray));
            alert(`There are ${SaveForLaterArray.length} amount of items in your save for later`);
            window.location.reload();
        }
        function displaySavedForLater() {
            let savedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SaveForLaterArray"));
            let displayArea = document.querySelector(".displayItems");

            displayArea.innerHTML = '';

            if (savedItems) {
                savedItems.forEach((item) => {
                    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    newDiv.textContent = "";
                    displayArea.appendChild(newDiv);

                    let displaySavedItems = document.createElement("p");
                    displaySavedItems.textContent = `${item.Name}: ${item.Description}`;
                    newDiv.appendChild(displaySavedItems);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```